# Insert into columns from specific rows and merge rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table (old WP export postmeta table with old custom fields), and need to combine multiple rows and clean them up:

```
post_id | company | meta_key | meta_value
11111     AAA       street     boulevard 1
11111     AAA       tel        12345678
11111     AAA       email      info@aaa.com
11111     AAA       website    http://aaa.com
22222     BBB       street     boulevard 2
22222     BBB       tel        47334949
22222     BBB       email      info@bbb.com
22222     BBB       website    http://bbb.com
```

What I need it to look like is the following:

```
newtable
post_id   company   street        tel      email         website
11111     AAA       boulevard 1   1234567  info@aaa.com  http://aaa.com
22222     BBB       boulevard 2   47334949 info@bbb.com  http://bbb.com
```

I have looked through all forum posts and tried dozens of syntaxes, none work, and I can't find the error. I have even tried to run a insert into syntax with a where condition from another table, since the ID needs to stay the same, so for example:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (street) VALUES (meta_value) WHERE oldtable.meta_key = 'street' AND oldtable.meta_key = newtable.post_id
```

Basically some fields need to become columns and some fields need to be inserted into those columens.

Any hints or tips are much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT company
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'email' THEN meta_value END) email 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'street' THEN meta_value END) street
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'tel' THEN meta_value END) tel 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'website' THEN meta_value END) website
  FROM eav 
 GROUP 
    BY company;
```

Comment: thank you, Strawberry! thanks to your code i managed to set up the new table with the respective colums, however, all fields contain the value "NULL" instead of the correct field information? also the main "company" colum contains some strange numbers and symbols?

Comment: hey again, sorry i made a mistake, your code worked perfectly. the first pages were filled with NULLs but the last ones contained all the necessary information perfectly sorted! thanks for your help and time! :)